# Aggregate Sorting in FeatherJS before hook for get request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, feathersjs, get-request

I need help on how to aggregate sorting for a get request.

**Aim**
I want to build a web API with FeatherJS and MongoDD. The web api will have the following sample dataset for food menu item (see below).

Sample Dataset

```
[
        {
          _id: 1,
          name: "Pizza",
          price: 10,
          expirydate: ISODate("2022-06-01T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
          _id: 2,
          name: "Chicken Burger",
          price: 5,
          expirydate: ISODate("2022-04-01T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
          _id: 3,
          name: "Pasta Salad",
          price: 0,
          expirydate: ISODate("2022-05-01T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
          _id: 4,
          name: "Veg Sandwich",
          price: 8,
          expirydate: ISODate("2022-03-01T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
          _id: 5,
          name: "Beef Burger",
          price: 5,
          expirydate: ISODate("2022-12-12T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
          _id: 6,
          name: "Fruit Sandwich",
          price: 8,
          expirydate: ISODate("2022-04-02T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
          _id: 7,
          name: "Pork Burger",
          price: 5,
          expirydate: ISODate("2022-07-21T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
          _id: 8,
          name: "Potato Salad",
          price: 0,
          expirydate: ISODate("2022-08-01T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
          _id: 9,
          name: "Fruit Salad",
          price: 0,
          expirydate: ISODate("2022-01-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    ]
```

**Sorting Required**
Before my frontend makes an HTTP Get Request from my api, I want to presort it. To do that, using featherjs, I create a before hook for find that allows me to pre-process/sort my dataset.

How I want to sort is to first sort the items into 2 groups first, price = 0 and price != 0. After that, I want the record inside the groups to be sort by expiry date (ascending order). After which I want to join the two groups together where the first group is that of price != 0 and the second group to be joined to its end.

The end result will be non-zero prices to appear first and to be sorted by expiry date in ascending order. After that, the items with zero prices to appear and also sorted by expiry date in ascending order. Like what I provided below.

Dataset after sorting

```
[  
    {
        name: "Veg Sandwich",
        price: 8,
        expirydate: ISODate("2022-03-01T00:00:00Z")  
    },  
    {
        name: "Chicken Burger",
        price: 5,    
        expirydate: ISODate("2022-04-01T00:00:00Z")
    },  
    {    
        name: "Fruit Sandwich",
        price: 8,
        expirydate: ISODate("2022-04-02T00:00:00Z")  
    },  
    {    
        name: "Pizza",    
        price: 10,    
        expirydate: ISODate("2022-06-01T00:00:00Z")  
    },  
    {    
        name: "Pork Burger",    
        price: 5,   
        expirydate: ISODate("2022-07-21T00:00:00Z")  
    },  
    {    
        name: "Beef Burger",    
        price: 5,    
        expirydate: ISODate("2022-12-12T00:00:00Z")  
    }, 
    {
        name: "Fruit Salad",    
        price: 0,    
        expirydate: ISODate("2022-01-01T00:00:00Z")  
    },  
    {    
        name: "Pasta Salad",    
        price: 0,    
        expirydate: ISODate("2022-05-01T00:00:00Z")  
    },  
    {    
        name: "Potato Salad",    
        price: 0,    
        expirydate: ISODate("2022-08-01T00:00:00Z")  
    }
]
```

Question: How do i write my before hook for find (get) such that the dataset could be sorted like the above.

**What I to do**
WIP, not sure if the code below will work.
Before Hook

```
db.food.aggregate([
  { $sort: { price: -1, expirydate: 1 } },
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten the answer through aggregate sort. Aggregate sorting means database operations are carried out in sequence called stages. To achieve that in my question, please find more details of my codes below.

Stage1:
Sort all food items by expiry date

Stage2:
Setup a condition to push the free food item (price = $0) into the free group, else into the not-free group.
As food items are already in ascending order of the expiry date, the food items in the group will also be in that order.

Stage3:
In order for the not free group to be in front, sort by descending order.

```
db.items.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: { expirydate: 1 }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: ["$price", 0] },
          then: "free",
          else: "notFree"
        }
      },
      fooditems: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { $_id: -1 }
  },
{
 $project: {
   _id: 0,
   items: {
    $concatArrays: ["$items"]
  }
}
   },
   {
     $unwind: "$items"
   },
)];
```